# Showing $\Bbb Q_8$ is nilpotent.

Tags: group-theory

My definition of nilpotent is

> ***Definition***: A group $G$ is said to be nilpotent if $C_{i}(G)=G$ for some $i$. Where $C_i(G)=\tau^{-1}(Z(G/C_{i-1}(G)))$ $$\tau:G\to G/C_{i-1}(G), \text{ by } \tau(a)=aC_{i-1}(G). $$ 
>   where $Z(G/C_{i-1}(G))$ is the center of $(G/C_{i-1}(G))$.

with this definition here how I tried to show $\Bbb Q_8$ is nilpotent.

Solution(Edited as [Bungo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/169852/bungo) suggested):  $C(G)=\{a\in G:ax=xa\ \forall x\in G\}$.

Claim:- $C(G)=\{1,-1\}$. $1$ is an identity element for $G$ so $1\in C(G)$. $-1\in C(G) \because -x=-x\Rightarrow (-1)x=x(-1)\ \forall x\in G$.

Now each of $\pm i,\pm j, \pm k$ are not in $C(G)$ because
\begin{align*}
   \text{Take }  &  x=k   \text{ for } \pm i  \Rightarrow (\pm i)k=\mp j\neq\pm j=k(\pm i)\\
                &  x=i   \text{ for } \pm j  \Rightarrow (\pm j)i=\mp k\neq\pm k=i(\pm j)\\
                &  x=j   \text{ for } \pm k  \Rightarrow (\pm k)j=\mp i\neq\pm i=j(\pm k)
\end{align*}
Now, $G/C(G)=\{aC(G),a\in G\}=\{\{\pm1\},\{\pm i\},\{\pm j\},\{\pm k\}\}$ which is abelian as it is of order $4$ hence $Z(G/C(G))=G/C(G)$. Define $\tau:G\to G/C(G)$ by $\tau(a)=aC(G)$. Define $\tau^{-1}: G/C(G)\to G$ by $\tau^{-1}(xC(G))=x$, then $\tau^{-1}$ is onto. Therefore, 
$$C_2(G)=\tau^{-1}(Z(G/C(G)))=\tau^{-1}(G/C(G))=G=\Bbb Q_8.$$

Comment: There is a typo, instead of $\pm k=i(\pm i)$ it should be $\pm k=i(\pm j)$, similar fix to $\pm i=j(\pm i)$, the solution seems good to me

Comment: @JulianP: Thanks! Edited.

Comment: Your definition of $C_i(G)$ doesn't seem right. If $\tau : G \rightarrow G/C_{i-1}$, how can $\tau^{-1}(G/C_{i-1})$ be anything but $G$? I think you mean to define $C_i(G) = \tau^{-1}(Z(G/C_{i-1}))$ where $Z(G/C_{i-1})$ is the center of $G/C_{i-1}$.

Comment: @Bungo: What a mess. You are right Thank you!

Comment: It's easy to fix. You can still argue as you did that $G/C(G) = \{\{\pm 1\}, \{\pm i\}, \{\pm j\}, \{\pm k\}\}$. Then simply observe that this group is abelian because it has order $4$. Therefore $Z(G/C(G))$ is all of $G/C(G)$. P.S. Give my regards to T-Bag and the Scofield brothers :-)

Comment: what is question ?

Answer (score 0):

There are equivalent conditions right.  Like G is finite nilpotent then G is isometric to product of its p-sylows subgroups. Using this you can prove any p-groups are nilpotent. In particularly this group in question.